# Variable type in javadoc methods eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Is there a way to have the type of the input variable for methods with javadoc in eclipse?

I know you can have as tags the name of the variables like:

```
/*
* param1
* param2
*/
```

But I'd like something like:

```
/*
* String param1:
* int param2:
* return int: 
*/
```

I've seen in Window-->Preferences->Java-->Code Style-->Code Templates but I can't see anything resembling the tags I need.

Thanks

Comment: That's a bad idea. Please read about the DRY principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 2):

No, the [javadoc tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) does not support this.

Why would you want this? In the documentation of a method that you generate with javadoc, the method signature already shows what the types of the parameters are.

Comment: Isn't it somewhat clearer to have the type for each variable directly when you read the doc instead of having to look at the signature?

Comment: Maybe, but the javadoc tool parses the documentation comment and formats it in a specific way into the generated HTML documentation. It expects that what you put after a `@param` tag has a specific format: `@param parameterName Description.` In other words, the first word after `@param` is seen as the parameter name; if you include the type, it will confuse the javadoc tool.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for making it clear, I'll try to get used to this notation

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi It would be possible to use a different Javadoc doclet which includes the type of the parameters at that point of the documentation. Though if there is a problem looking at the signaure, then you likely have too many parameters for your method or constructor.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following comment template - as far as I can see, this is exactly what you want :-)

```
/**
 * ${field_type} ${field}
 */
```

*EDIT*: Use the above template in Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Code Style >> Code Templates for Comments >> Fields

[image: Code Templates Preference Page]

Now you can use the command Generate Element Comment (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (I think) or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Mac) with the cursor on an field to generate the correct comment.

Comment: But the javadoc tool will not understand this, so that the generated documentation most likely isn't going to look like you expect.

Comment: I understand that. But Eclipse will in fact expand it to use the correct type and name of the filed in question. It will change if the actual type or name changes, though...

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell I'm not sure I understand. See the expanded answer.

Comment: I think OP was asking about parameters, not fields.

Comment: It is not working, I modified the fields as you said but now when I generate the doc for a method I still have the template for methods (as i excpect)...

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi you're right. I didn't catch that you ment methods and not fields. For methods, you "just" have the built-in support with 'param' javadoc